# pip install failed using pkgs from pip download

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, pip

I have a special need that i need install resource pkg at a pc without network.
So i choose to use pip download first, and copy all downloaded files to this pc then pip install.

```
$ pip download resource
$ ls
JsonForm-0.0.2-py2-none-any.whl  PyYAML-3.12.tar.gz                            Resource-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl  jsonschema-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl  six-1.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
JsonSir-0.0.2-py2-none-any.whl   Python_EasyConfig-0.1.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl  functools32-3.2.3-2.zip
```

copy all files to the special pc to do:

```
$ pip install Resource-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Processing ./Resource-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting python-easyconfig>=0.1.0 (from Resource==0.2.0)
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 792, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 501, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 643, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 315, in increment
    total -= 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'
```

It seems dependences not installed. I have a rough way to fix it:

```
$ pip install six-1.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
$ pip install PyYAML-3.12.tar.gz
$ pip install Python_EasyConfig-0.1.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
$ pip install JsonSir-0.0.2-py2-none-any.whl 
$ pip install functools32-3.2.3-2.zip
$ pip install jsonschema-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
$ pip install JsonForm-0.0.2-py2-none-any.whl
$ pip install Resource-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

But it is so ugly, is there any good way to do this?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pip install Resource-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl --no-index --find-links `pwd`
```

Ｉ find this cmd is ok.